# Tweak a PHP image download script to rename and resize

Tags: php, image, curl, download

I used this great script for an older project to download images to use for a movie review site. How can I tweak it to be able to save the image as a dynamically generated name and also resize it to, say 60px x 60px? Thanks!

```
$img[]='http://site.com/img.150x150.jpg';
foreach($img as $i){
    save_image($i);
    if(getimagesize(basename($i))){
        echo 'Image ' . basename($i) . ' Downloaded OK';
    }else{
        echo 'Image ' . basename($i) . ' Download Failed';
    }
}
function save_image($img,$fullpath='basename'){
    if($fullpath=='basename'){
        $fullpath = basename($img);
    }
    $ch = curl_init ($img);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        unlink($fullpath);
    }
    $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image resizer class class

```
class Process{
    // List of supported image formats.     
    private $valid_ext = array( 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'bmp', 'wbmp' );

    // Whether or not that script should continue
    private $halt = false;

    // Image Configuration array and Source Image
    public $errmsg = "";
    var $image = array();
    var $s_image;

    public function render($source){        
        $this->s_image = $source;  
        //set the image to this class attr for other to be accessible
        //list the image height and width
        list($this->image['width'], $this->image['height']) = getimagesize($source);  

        //get the image extension       
        $this->image['extension'] = strtolower(preg_replace('/^.*\.([^.]+)$/D', '$1', $this->s_image));
        if (!(in_array( $this->image['extension'], $this->valid_ext))){         
            $this->errmsg = "invalid format";
            $this->halt = true; 
            return false;  //terminate the function if type format is not correct
        }

        //i think mime type should be checked instead of extension 
        //well in that case i will do sometime  

        //create image
        switch($this->image['extension']){
            case 'png';
                $this->image['render'] = imagecreatefrompng( $this->s_image );
                    imagealphablending( $this->image['render'], false );
                    imagesavealpha( $this->image['render'], true );
                break;
            case 'jpg';
                    $this->image['render'] = imagecreatefromjpeg( $this->s_image );
                break;
            case 'jpeg';
                    $this->image['render'] = imagecreatefromjpeg( $this->s_image );
                break;
            case 'gif';
                    $this->image['render'] = imagecreatefromgif( $this->s_image );
                break;
            case 'bmp';
                    $this->image['render'] = imagecreatefromwbmp( $this->s_image );
                break;
            case 'wbmp';
                    $this->image['render'] = imagecreatefromwbmp( $this->s_image );
                break;
            default: 
                    $this->errmsg = "invalid format";
                    $this->halt = true;
                return false;
                break;
        }       
    }

    public function contrain($width, $height){      
        if(!($this->halt)){
            if($this->image['extension'] == 'gif'){
                        $this->image['composite'] = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                        imagecopyresample($this->image['composite'], $this->image['render'], 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                $width, $height, $this->image['width'], $this->image['height'] );

                        $this->image['colorcount'] = imagecolorstotal( $this->image['render'] );

                        imagetruecolortopalette( $this->image['composite'], true, $this->image['colorcount'] );

                        imagepalettecopy( $this->image['composite'], $this->image['render'] );

                        $this->image['transparentcolor'] = imagecolortransparent( $this->image['render'] );

                        imagefill( $this->image['composite'], 0, 0, $this->image['transparentcolor'] );

                        imagecolortransparent( $this->image['composite'], $this->image['transparentcolor'] );
            } else {

                        $this->image['composite'] = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

                        imagecopyresampled( $this->image['composite'], $this->image['render'], 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                            $width, $height, $this->image['width'], $this->image['height'] );
            }
        }else{
            $this->halt = true;
            $this->errmsg = "Execution halted";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function proportion($max_width, $max_height){        
        if (!( $this->halt)){

            if($this->image['extension'] == 'gif'){

                $this->image['ratio'] = ( $this->image['width'] > $this->image['height'] ) ? $max_width / $this->image['width'] : $max_height/$this->image['height'];

                if( $this->image['width'] > $max_width || $this->image['height'] > $max_height ) { 
                    $new_width = $this->image['width'] * $this->image['ratio']; 
                    $new_height = $this->image['height'] * $this->image['ratio']; 
                }else{
                    $new_width = $this->image['width']; 
                    $new_height = $this->image['height'];
                }

                $this->image['composite'] = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

                imagecopyresampled( $this->image['composite'], $this->image['render'], 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->image['width'], $this->image['height'] );

                $this->image['colorcount'] = imagecolorstotal( $this->image['render'] );

                imagetruecolortopalette( $this->image['composite'], true, $this->image['colorcount'] );

                imagepalettecopy( $this->image['composite'], $this->image['render'] );

                $this->image['transparentcolor'] = imagecolortransparent( $this->image['render'] );

                imagefill( $this->image['composite'], 0, 0, $this->image['transparentcolor'] );

                imagecolortransparent( $this->image['composite'], $this->image['transparentcolor'] );

            }else{
                $this->image['ratio'] = ( $this->image['width'] > $this->image['height'] ) ? $max_width / $this->image['width'] : $max_height/$this->image['height']; 

                if( $this->image['width'] > $max_width || $this->image['height'] > $max_height ) { 

                    $new_width = $this->image['width'] * $this->image['ratio']; 

                    $new_height = $this->image['height'] * $this->image['ratio']; 
                }else{
                    $new_width = $this->image['width']; 

                    $new_height = $this->image['height'];
                } 

                $this->image['composite'] = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );

                imagecopyresampled( $this->image['composite'], $this->image['render'], 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->image['width'], $this->image['height'] );
            }
        } else {
                $this->errmsg = "Execution halted";
            $this->halt = true;
            return false;
        }       
    }

    public function output($quality = 100){     
        if(!(is_numeric($quality))){
            $quality = 100;
        }
        if(!($this->halt)){
            switch($this->image['extension']){
            case 'png';
                header('Content-Type: image/png');
                imagepng($this->image['composite'], null, null );
                break;
            case 'jpg';
                header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($this->image['composite'], null, $quality);
                break;
            case 'jpeg';
                header( 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' );
                imagejpeg($this->image['composite'], null, $quality);
                break;
            case 'gif';
                header( 'Content-Type: image/gif' );
                imagegif($this->image['composite'], null, $quality);
                break;
            case 'bmp';
                header('Content-Type: image/wbmp' );
                imagewbmp($this->image['composite'], null, null);
                break;
            case 'wbmp';
                header('Content-Type: image/wbmp' );
                imagewbmp($this->image['composite'], null, null);
                break;
            default: 
                $this->errmsg = "invalid format";
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }else{
            $this->errmsg = "Execution halted";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function saveto($destination, $filename, $quality = 100){        
        if(!(is_numeric($quality))){
            $quality = 100;
        }
        if(!($this->halt)){
            switch($this->image['extension']){
            case 'png';
                imagepng($this->image['composite'],  $destination.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename, null);
                break;
            case 'jpg';
                imagejpeg($this->image['composite'], $destination.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename, $quality );
                break;
            case 'jpeg';
                imagejpeg($this->image['composite'], $destination.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename, $quality );
                break;
            case 'gif';
                imagegif($this->image['composite'],  $destination.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename, $quality );
                break;
            case 'bmp';
                imagewbmp($this->image['composite'], $destination.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename, null);
                break;
            case 'wbmp';
                imagewbmp($this->image['composite'], $destination.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename, null);
                break;
            default: 
                $this->errmsg = "invalid format";
                return false;
                break;
            }
        }else{
            $this->errmsg = "Execution halted";
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function clear_cache(){
        imagedestroy( $this->image['composite'] );
        imagedestroy( $this->image['render'] );
        unset($this->image);
        unset($this->s_image);
        $this->halt = false;
    }
}
```

And usage

```
$process = new Process();

$process->render($filepath);

$process->proportion($width, $height);

$process->saveto($upload_path, $filename, $quality); //$quality is in %
```

Comment: Thanks for the example I will try it. Just to make sure this class will be a totally new solution that performs the download, rename and resize? If so is filepath the image url?

Comment: @Joseph well there is a function called `stringtoimage` that will convert string into `image` type variable. And if you do please alert me. I would like to have that too.

Comment: I get the following error message 
Warning: imagejpeg() [function.imagejpeg]: Unable to open '/chosenupload_path/chosenfilename' for writing: No such file or directory in mysite/site.se/public_html/handleimgs.php on line 200

Comment: @Joseph it's because the file is not found. First make sure by using function `file_exists($filepath)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [imagecopyresized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) function example.

Answer (score 0):

Save the image in a Folder like Cache. If you have performed the function `save_image()`, execute a function that resize the image and save the image under a new name. Then you delete the image from the `cache` folder.

Comment: I have tried to insert something above echo 'Image ' . basename($i) . ' Downloaded OK'; in order to perform additional functions when the image is downloaded but I havent succeded yet, any suggestions?

Comment: For example, you can do it this way: `if(getimagesize(basename($i))){ echo 'Image ' . basename($i) . ' Downloaded OK'; resize_image($i); }`